# How do I iterate over an array when the array elements are controls?

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, for-loop, ms-access-2016

I need to iterate over an array of control names to change their `TabIndex` values.

This is what I've tried:

```
Dim ctls As Variant
Dim i As Variant

ctls = Array("Text2")

For Each i In ctls
    i.TabIndex = 1
Next
```

...but this gives me the error: `Error 424: Object Required`. How do I make the array element be recognized as an object?

Comment: `Me.Controls(i).TabIndex = 1`

Comment: But only the last touched control will have TabIndex set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

    ctrl.TabIndex = 1

Next
```